# DotnetNuke - How can I load module dynamically in existing tab?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a situation where I have predefined tab name payments.

Now I want to load my payment module inside it whenever Tab is being called.

How can I Achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Just write your own module:

Watch Tutorial here:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/437/view/details/dotnetnuke-explained-basic-module-development

Other videos in Development section
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/videos